# Is there a command for clearing the logcat?

Tags: eclipse, shortcut

I am tired of clearing it with the button. With a command would be more easy, or automatically. Is there a command to clear it IN ECLIPSE? 
I mean, not a command in the CMD but in eclipse, the shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

Using command line, write the following command:

```
adb logcat -c
```

I hope it will do the job :)